# Methods are executed at the same time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with the following issue in my game:

I have a grid represented by a map and I've attached to it a script called "Movement". The function "MoveToTile" works well:

```
public void MoveToTile()// Function to move the players
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //raycast checks and returns an object, if it's a tile, the unit moves
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            ismoving = true;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Tile")
                {
                    //checks if the tile is available based on the max movement of the unit
                    Tile tileAux = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>();
                    Jogador scriptJog = player.GetComponent<Jogador>();
                    if ((tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) + (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) >= -movMax && (tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) + (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) <= movMax)
                    {
                        if ((tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) - (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) >= -movMax && (tileAux.TilePostion.x - scriptJog.GridPosition.x) - (tileAux.TilePostion.y - scriptJog.GridPosition.y) <= movMax)
                        {
                            targetPosition = (hit.transform.position);
                            targetPosition.y = posY;
                            moveEnabled = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //player moves until reaches the position
        if (player.transform.position != targetPosition)
        {
            player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, targetPosition, velocity);
            if (player.transform.position == targetPosition)
                ismoving = false;
        }

        //if player reaches position, it's deselected
        if (moveEnabled && !ismoving)
        {
            player.GetComponent<Jogador>().isPlayer = false;
            moveEnabled = false;
            if (gameManager.playerTurn == 1)
            {
                gameManager.PontoAcaop1--;

            }
            if (gameManager.playerTurn == 2)
            {
                gameManager.PontoAcaop2--;

            }

            if (gameManager.playerTurn == 3)
            {
                gameManager.PontoAcaop1--;
            }
        }

        if (gameManager.PontoAcaop1 == 0)
        {
            gameManager.playerTurn = 2;
            TurnEnd();
            gameManager.PontoAcaop1 = 4;
        }

        if (gameManager.PontoAcaop2 == 0)
        {
            gameManager.playerTurn = 1;
            TurnEnd();
            gameManager.PontoAcaop2 = 4;
        }

    }
```

But in this script there're other two functions called "TeslaShooting" and "CrossAttack". I call them inside the Update method. However, the problem is that they are executed at the same time, for instance, when the player shoots with the character Tesla, I just want "TeslaShooting" to be executed, but it doesn't work.

"TeslaShooting" is this method here:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)&& SpawBala.tag == "Bala1" && gameManager.playerTurn == 1)
        {
            //raycast checks and returns an object, if it's a tile, the unit shoots
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                //checks if the tile is available based on the line and column of the unit
                Tile tileAux = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>();
                Jogador scriptJog = player.GetComponent<Jogador>();

                if (tileAux.TilePostion.x == scriptJog.GridPosition.x || tileAux.TilePostion.y == scriptJog.GridPosition.y)
                {
                    if (tileAux.TilePostion.x > scriptJog.GridPosition.x)
                        tileAux.TilePostion.x = 5;
                    else
                        tileAux.TilePostion.x = 0;

                    if (tileAux.TilePostion.y > scriptJog.GridPosition.y)
                        tileAux.TilePostion.y = 5;
                    else
                        tileAux.TilePostion.y = 0;

                    //instantiates the bullet
                    GameObject tiro = Instantiate(projetil, SpawBala.transform.position, SpawBala.transform.rotation);
                    Rigidbody BalaRigid = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                    BalaRigid.velocity = SpawBala.transform.forward * ProjetilVeloc * Time.deltaTime;
                    gameManager.PontoAcaop1--;

                }
            }
        }
```

And "CrossAttack" is this one:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)&&SpawCruz.tag=="SpawnCruz"&&gameManager.playerTurn==1)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Tile")
                {
                    SpawCruz.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
                    Instantiate(Cruz, SpawCruz.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    gameManager.PontoAcaop1--;
                }
            }
        }
```

I set the playerTurn is this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jogador : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Mapa mapa;

    public Vector2Int GridPosition;

    public bool isPlayer = false;

    public float Health = 50f;

    public GameObject Spawnador1;

    public int isWhichPlayer;

    public TurnManager gameManager;


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!mapa) mapa = FindObjectOfType<Mapa>();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var tile in mapa.GridMatriz)
        {
            //tile.jogador = this;
        }

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.transform == this.transform && (isWhichPlayer == gameManager.playerTurn))
            {

                mapa.GetComponent<Movimentação>().TurnEnd();
                isPlayer = true;
                mapa.GetComponent<Movimentação>().TurnStart();
                Debug.Log("clicou");

            }

        }

        CheckHealth();

    }


    public void CheckHealth()//If the player's health is 0 he goes to the base
    {

        if (Health <= 0 && this.tag == "Player")
        {

            this.transform.position = new Vector3(Spawnador1.transform.position.x, Spawnador1.transform.position.y, Spawnador1.transform.position.z);
            Health = 50;
        }


        if (Health <= 0 && this.tag == "Player2")
        {

            this.transform.position = new Vector3(Spawnador1.transform.position.x, Spawnador1.transform.position.y, Spawnador1.transform.position.z);
            Health = 50;

        }

    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understant your code, but i see that this two if's

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)&& SpawBala.tag == "Bala1" && gameManager.playerTurn == 1
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)&&SpawCruz.tag=="SpawnCruz"&&gameManager.playerTurn==1)
```

Can be true both in the same time. Shouldn't you add somthing more in this if statement?
In each method you shoot the ray, this is can be problem too. I think you could get RayHit when you click on Enemy only once, and after that you should check what character should do: shoot tesla or crossAttack. In code you pasted i can't see that.